# What does Silence do?

Tags: rounds

In *Rounds* the SILENCE card adds a new on-block effect that 'silences enemies nearby'.  It's not exactly clear what this means though in the context of the game.

[image: SILENCE - Blocking silences enemies nearby]

The block does have a new visual effect and it seems to apply a red X on top of opponent players' faces for a short time if they're caught in it, but what does the Silence effect do, or prevent the opponent from doing?

[image: Silence on-block visual effect]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/RoundsTheGame/comments/o2ml12/how_does_silence_work/), *Silence* effect stops victim ability to shoot and block for few seconds.